# Drupal different theme for ip

Tags: php, drupal

How can I load a completely different theme for a user with a specific IP address (mine) just for developing in Drupal?

Answer (score 4):

The first step is to grant permission to the user's role -- the "select different theme" permission is under "system" in the permissions table.

EDIT: Make a new user role only for you, and enable it only for that user role.

Once you've set that permission, the user can select any of the enabled themes in their edit account screen.

Another option you have is the Switchtheme, or ThemeKey module.
https://drupal.org/project/switchtheme
https://drupal.org/project/themekey

Comment: Cheers for that! Mart

Comment: @Martin: [Please read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and [this FAQ question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).